# Existe um laço de repetição por trás do código de um CTE?

Tags: sql, loop, característica-linguagem, tsql

Estou quebrando a cabeça para entender como um comando tão simples pode gerar valores de 1 até o 100.

Há um laço de repetição por trás de um CTE? Pois no código abaixo existe um `WHERE` e não um `WHILE`.

```
WITH CTE_EXEMPLO AS 
(
SELECT 1 AS QNT
UNION ALL 
SELECT QNT + 1 FROM CTE_EXEMPLO WHERE QNT < 100
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_EXEMPLO
```

Comment: Completando a resposta do @Maniero, sempre lembre de pesquisar sobre qual banco de dados você está aplicando a CTE. Cada *engine* de cada banco trabalha de uma forma e o desempenho pode variar muito podendo, em alguns casos, não ser a melhor saída utilizar CTE's.

Comment: @DouglasVieira O código que postou é um exemplo de CTE recursiva.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é só o CTE, é todo o SQL. SQL é uma linguagem (não de programação como alguns acham) declarativa, ou seja, você diz o que quer e é problema do *engine* que está por trás dela resolver isso da melhor forma que ele puder. Então meio que ele interpreta o que seu código deseja e manda o computador executar, ao contrário da maioria das linguagens de programação tradicionais que são imperativas o código diz mais exatamente o que fazer em vez do que deseja.

Só deixando claro que códigos mais imperativos podem se tornar um pouco declarativos, desde uma simples abstração até sintaxes e abstrações mais fortes que realmente mudam a forma de fazer por completo.

Então de certa forma tem um laço sim, mas bem de certa forma, porque a forma como executa é problema do *engine* e se pensar bem, o conceito de laço já é abstrato, um computador não entende isso, então existe uma repetição de execução, como ocorre o tempo todo em tudo o que executa e você nem está percebendo. De alguma forma isso será interpretado e executado através de uma repetição bastante complexa.

O `SELECT` simples já fará um "laço" de alguma forma na maioria dos casos (o primeiro é um que não fará isto, não tem vários dados para avaliar). Este CTE em si não tem laço algum, o que está nele é que tem.

Por isso que eu digo para as pessoas aprenderem como o computador funciona, com profundidade, e depois vai subindo as abstrações em cima dele, isto dá uma força muito grande pra programar bem. Eu não acredito em programadores que não sabem isso, mesmo alguns experientes e que são considerados bons por muitos, se não souber isso eu garanto que são supervalorizados, pelo menos mais do que deveriam.

Comment: Neste caso eu devo estudar o engine do SQL Server?

Comment: Não sei, não conheço sua necessidade.

Comment: Só queria entender de ponta a ponta como esse comando é executado.

Comment: Tem que começar pelos fundamentos da computação, não tem atalhos, caso contrário aprenderá mais ou menos e servirá para nada, ou até piorará porque criará um monte de mitos por entender tudo pela metade.